# Android SDK Platform Java SDK Dependency Version Requirement Table

Tags: android, java-6, jdk1.7

Is there any official documentation on [**developer.android.com**](https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/index.html) that states which version of the **Java SDK** each **Android SDK** platform depends on?

I currently have *1.7.0_55* for *API 23*, however newer versions are available, the latest being *7u80* (which I assume is *1.7.0_80*).

**Can I simply use the latest version of *JDK 1.7*, or do I need a specific version?**

The next time an update is available for *API 23*, should I also be updating *JDK 1.7* accordingly (either to the latest, or whatever is specified, wherever that may be)?

---

**UPDATE**

The below table specifies requirements for building the actual OS source, and though I'd like to think that it applies when targeting the corresponding SDK Platforms, I'm not positive.

https://source.android.com/source/requirements

> JDK
>
> See Installing the JDK for the prebuilt path and installation
>   instructions for older versions.
>
> - Android 7.0 (Nougat) - Android 8.0 (O release): Ubuntu - OpenJDK 8, Mac OS - jdk 8u45 or newer
> - Android 5.x (Lollipop) - Android 6.0 (Marshmallow): Ubuntu - OpenJDK 7, Mac OS - jdk-7u71-macosx-x64.dmg
> - Android 2.3.x (Gingerbread) - Android 4.4.x (KitKat): Ubuntu - Java JDK 6, Mac OS - Java JDK 6
> - Android 1.5 (Cupcake) - Android 2.2.x (Froyo): Ubuntu - Java JDK 5

Answer (score 0):

I can't point to specific page in in documentation, but from practical point I have been programming for android last 4 years and update JDK very occasionally once a year, by not connected with Android reasons. 
So any version of JDK 7/8 will be ok for any api version.

Comment: N(24) - O(26): jdk 8u45 or newer, L(21) - M(23): jdk-7u71, G(9)-K(20): jdk 6, C(3) - F(8): jdk 5 https://source.android.com/source/requirements

Comment: ... however that's for building the source. I'd like to imagine the versioning table applies to building apps for an SDK as well, but am not positive.

Comment: In any case jdk 8u45 will be ok for any android api, cause it have backward compatibility.

Comment: I will give it a try. If java truly is backward compatible, then I guess you answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

The JDK is specified for building the projects but its not the same specification used by the Compliance_Level of the Project you are building.

The point is that the code doesn't have the features from JDK, but its limited from the compiler features specified by Android.

For example: Having JDK 1.8 doesnt give access for Lambdas. (retrolambda gives and a native solution will be added in Android 3.0)

Until AS 2.3+ the Java 1.7 spec is used.

From AS 3.0 (currently on beta) the Java 1.8 spec is used.

Updating the machine JDK doesnt interfer on your code.

Comment: Is there a minimum machine JDK version required for a particular API level (say 23 in this case)? I realize that Android Studio itself has it's own JDK requirements.

Comment: AndroidStudio JDK does offers itself to update when needed, for machine path you have the system requirement on your question.